# Compile PHP - bison version?

Tags: php, debian

```
checking for bison version... invalid
configure: WARNING: This bison version is not
           supported for regeneration of the Zend/PHP parsers
           (found: 3.0, min: 204, excluded: 3.0).
```

Tried installing PHP7 and PHP5.6, I'm using Debian 8.4/Jessie, do I need to downgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are requirements listed in [PHP build notes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php):

```
bison:
PHP 5.4: 1.28, 1.35, 1.75, 1.875, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.4
PHP 5.5: 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7
PHP 5.6: 2.4 or later, excluding 3.0 only (3.0.1 and later are OK)
PHP 7.0: 2.4 or later
```

Comment: Thanks for looking up the versions. My bison --version is `bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.2` and it doesn't work with PHP 7 nor with PHP 5.6.

Comment: Well,. I won't be much of more help as I haven't built PHP myself for ages, but perhaps checking dotdeb's repo could be of any help: https://github.com/gplessis/dotdeb-php